# Releasing semaphore in atomic context [linux kernel]?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, semaphore

While sending a `bio down` for write IO, I acquire a semaphore (`down_interruptible`). And in the IO completion routine i.e. inside `bio_end_io`, I release the semaphore (`up`).

I know that acquiring a semaphore in completion routine is illegal as the blocking operations are not allowed in atomic context. But does the same restriction apply while releasing the semaphore?